# "To be a part of something bigger than oneself" word ideas

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, emotions

I'm searching for a word that sums up the feeling of being a small part of a larger/cosmic interconnectedness. Not in a way that diminishes the importance of the individual, but rather one that highlights the beauty of global community.

Any and all suggestions (even if they don't align perfectly with my definition) are greatly appreciated!

This is for a list of possible name I'm compiling for a new charitable foundation.

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence, with a blank where you might place this word, to assist people in thinking about what the appropriate word might be?

Answer (score 0):

My humble suggestions: *a grain of sand, a drop in the ocean.*

Small and apparently insignificant as they are, they contribute to the formation of huge deserts and seas.

Answer (score 0):

## Synergistic

from [Synergy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synergy):

> Synergy is the creation of a whole that is greater than the simple sum
> of its parts. The term synergy comes from the Attic Greek word
> συνεργία synergia from synergos, συνεργός, meaning "working
> together".

[Synergistic](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/synergistic): -

> When something is synergistic, it means various parts are working
> together to produce an enhanced result. If you’ve just heard a
> synergistic symphony, the musicians must have played very well
> together.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but you may consider "***Chip in!***" or "***Chipping in!***".

Collins:

> **[chip in](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/chip-in)**
>   *verb* (*adverb*) *informal*
>   **1.**  **to contribute** (money, time, etc) **to a cause** or fund
>
> Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers

Answer (score 0):

Freud described "oceanic" as a feeling of oneness with the world. The narrow Freudian meaning refers to the feeling an infant has before it learns there are others in the world. (See, Wikipedia) By extension, it encompasses a self-awareness that one is part of a larger interconnectedness.